# copy information from therr workbooks and paste to final one with python

Tags: python, python-3.x

i dont have big experience in python so i turn to you guys to understand if it is possible to simplify the code that i wrote.

the objetive of this code is to copy the information from 3 seperate excel documents (in all of them the info is in the first sheet) and paste to a final document in specific sheet each one of them, the code is working, but i feel that it can be writen alot better, can anyone have the time to review it please? thanks in advance.

```
# importing openpyxl module
import openpyxl as xl;
  
# opening the source excel file nr1
HitsByPeriod ="/Users/paulocosta/Downloads/HitsByPeriod_Teste_Python.xlsx"
wb1 = xl.load_workbook(HitsByPeriod)
ws1 = wb1.worksheets[0]

# opening the destination excel file 
filename1 ="/Users/paulocosta/Downloads/GestaoCampanhasTestePython.xlsx"
wb2 = xl.load_workbook(filename1)
ws2 = wb2.worksheets[2] 
  
# calculate total number of rows and columns in source excel file
mr = ws1.max_row
mc = ws1.max_column
  
# copying the cell values from source excel file to destination excel file
for i in range (1, mr + 1):
    for j in range (1, mc + 1):
        # reading cell value from source excel file
        c = ws1.cell(row = i, column = j)
  
        # writing the read value to destination excel file
        ws2.cell(row = i, column = j).value = c.value
  
# saving the destination excel file
wb2.save(str(filename1))

# opening the source excel file nr2
CalledHits ="/Users/paulocosta/Downloads/CalledHits_Teste_Python.xlsx"
wb1 = xl.load_workbook(CalledHits)
ws1 = wb1.worksheets[0]

# opening the destination excel file 
filename1 ="/Users/paulocosta/Downloads/GestaoCampanhasTestePython.xlsx"
wb2 = xl.load_workbook(filename1)
ws2 = wb2.worksheets[3] 
  
# calculate total number of rows and columns in source excel file
mr = ws1.max_row
mc = ws1.max_column
  
# copying the cell values from source excel file to destination excel file
for i in range (1, mr + 1):
    for j in range (1, mc + 1):
        # reading cell value from source excel file
        c = ws1.cell(row = i, column = j)
  
        # writing the read value to destination excel file
        ws2.cell(row = i, column = j).value = c.value
  
# saving the destination excel file
wb2.save(str(filename1))

# opening the source excel file nr3
WebsiteResults ="/Users/paulocosta/Downloads/Website_Teste_Python.xlsx"
wb1 = xl.load_workbook(WebsiteResults)
ws1 = wb1.worksheets[0]


# opening the destination excel file 
filename1 ="/Users/paulocosta/Downloads/GestaoCampanhasTestePython.xlsx"
wb2 = xl.load_workbook(filename1)
ws2 = wb2.worksheets[4] 
  
# calculate total number of rows and columns in source excel file
mr = ws1.max_row
mc = ws1.max_column
  
# copying the cell values from source excel file to destination excel file
for i in range (1, mr + 1):
    for j in range (1, mc + 1):
        # reading cell value from source excel file
        c = ws1.cell(row = i, column = j)
  
        # writing the read value to destination excel file
        ws2.cell(row = i, column = j).value = c.value
  
# saving the destination excel file
wb2.save(str(filename1))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import openpyxl as xl


def copy_data(source_file, destination_file, source_sheet_index, destination_sheet_index):
    # Open the source Excel file and worksheet
    wb_source = xl.load_workbook(source_file)
    ws_source = wb_source.worksheets[0]

    # Open the destination Excel file and worksheet
    wb_destination = xl.load_workbook(destination_file)
    ws_destination = wb_destination.worksheets[destination_sheet_index]

    # Copy data from source to destination
    for row in ws_source.iter_rows():
        for cell in row:
            ws_destination[cell.coordinate].value = cell.value

    # Save the destination Excel file
    wb_destination.save(destination_file)

# Specify the file paths and sheet indices for each copy operation
copy_operations = [
    ("/Users/paulocosta/Downloads/HitsByPeriod_Teste_Python.xlsx", "/Users/paulocosta/Downloads/GestaoCampanhasTestePython.xlsx", 0, 2),
    ("/Users/paulocosta/Downloads/CalledHits_Teste_Python.xlsx", "/Users/paulocosta/Downloads/GestaoCampanhasTestePython.xlsx", 0, 3),
    ("/Users/paulocosta/Downloads/Website_Teste_Python.xlsx", "/Users/paulocosta/Downloads/GestaoCampanhasTestePython.xlsx", 0, 4)
]

# Perform the copy operations
for source_file, destination_file, source_sheet_index, destination_sheet_index in copy_operations:
    copy_data(source_file, destination_file, source_sheet_index, destination_sheet_index)
```

To Improve/ Optimize the code

- avoiding redundant code
- enhancing readability using functions

This will enhance and reduce the code and will have a chance to Improve more.